# Unable to replace a string with another string in java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string and want to replace certain charactes in it.
Input `String = "abc test=0 test1=123 test2=764"`
Output `String = "abc test=$test test1=$test1 test2=$test2"`

I have tried couple of things using replace and replaceAll in java.
For example :

```
String abc = directiveValue.replaceAll("test%", test+"=$"+test);
```

or

```
String abc = directiveValue.replaceAll("test[.*]", test+"=$"+test);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match:

```
(test\d*)=\S*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eTN47U/1)

And replace with the dollar sign between the 2 capture groups `$1=\$$1`

```
System.out.println(
    "abc test=0 test1=123 test2=764"
        .replaceAll(
          "(test\\d*)=\\S*",
          "$1=\\$$1"
        )
);
```

Output

```
abc test=$test test1=$test1 test2=$test2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a regex replacement:

```java
String input = "abc test=0 test1=123 test2=764";
String output = input.replaceAll("(\\w+)=\\w+", "$1=\\$$1");
System.out.println(output);

// abc test=$test test1=$test1 test2=$test2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using VScode, I will use this `(test)(\d?)(=)(\b.+?\b)`

and replace with `$1$2$3$test$2`

I hope it inspires you with your java implementation. :)